# Preserve indentation formatting when using C++20 designated initializers (VS2019)

Tags: c++, visual-studio, formatting, designated-initializer

Is there a way to get Visual Studio 2019 to preserve existing indentation when writing typing `.` to start typing the next field?

```
MyStruct a =
{
    .asd = 12,
.foo = 1,
}
```

While typing the following code, as soon as I type `.` for the foo field with the cursor right under `.` in the asd field VS removes all spaces and not even `Ctrl + Z` gets me back on the indentation I want.

I've gone through the extensive list of options in `Text Editor > C++ > Formatting > Spacing` but couldn't find one to disable this behaviour.

Comment: I wouldn't expect VS2019 to properly format a C++20 feature.

Comment: Fair point indeed

Comment: I've just checked on my installation of VS Community 2019 version 16.11.26, and designated initializers are being formatted correctly. Maybe you just need to update to a more recent version of VS2019.

Comment: Just tried latest 2019 and 2022 and I'm getting this behaviour in both, even with a fresh install

Comment: There clearly is a setting somewhere because, when I type in the code you quote, I don't get the behaviour you describe but a maintained indentation for the `.foo = ...` line. Now it's just a matter of looking for the setting that changes the behaviour ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this was caused not by Visual Studio, but by the extension Visual Assist X. Disabling "Convert dot to -> in C/C++" (in Visual Assist Options > Editor) for some reason fixes this.